# As all the member variables of java LinkedList is transient, what will be the use of implementing Serializable?

Tags: java

1) In LinkedList implementation all the 3 member varaibles size, first, last are transient, then what is the use of implementing serializable?

2) What will be persisted when we try to serialize a LinkedList?

Answer (score 11):

You'll notice `LinkedList` has `writeObject` and `readObject` methods. These write/read the size of the list and write/read each object in the list.

Note that these methods (but also the fields) are private so the implementation may change. Don't depend on it. Depend on the interfaces.

Comment: Otherwise serializing would be by default, which would be recursive, and for a large list would easily blow the stack.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `readObject()` and `writeObject()`. It will serialize entries of the List not the list itself, and reconstructs it from the entries.